# node.js - Capture debug output from module

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

I need to capture debug information while I make a *require* call to find out why some packages are not found.

In *Module* (internal module.js) there are several **debug** calls such as:

```
  if (parent) {
      debug('looking for %j in %j', id, paths);
  }
```

What do I need to do to capture this debug information?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`debug()` is a function that was created using [`util.debuglog()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_debuglog_section), which means that if you set the correct environment variable, the debug messages will be written to `stderr`, which you can then capture to a file (for instance):

```
env NODE_DEBUG=module node your-app.js 2> debug.log
```

**EDIT**: to capture these messages from within your own app, I think you have to resort to monkeypatching, for instance `console.error()`

```
let error = console.error.bind(console);
console.error = function() {
  if (arguments[1] !== 'MODULE') {
    return error.apply(this, arguments);
  }
  console.log('error log', arguments);
};
```

This code needs to run before any of the `require()` statements that you want to track, and it's not very robust (if the implementation of `util.debuglog` ever changes, it might break).

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to capture stderr within the node.js application?